# load onclick jquery data json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have trouble, I want when pressing the direct data emerging data does not appear ..

html :

```
   <button onclick="tes();">Load Data</button>
   <table id="personDataTable">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
      </tr>        
   </table>
```

Jquery :

```
function tes(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        drawTable(data);
    }
});
}
function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}
function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.firstName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName + "</td>"));
}
```

if there is something wrong with the function test() ?

Comment: Move `$("#personDataTable").append(row);` to the end of function. You also have typo its `onclick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `onclick` not `onclik`

Try this

```
<button onclick="tes();">Load Data</button>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: tes is not defined

Comment: Inline script function or external js function?

Comment: function test() look above

Comment: yes ..i use tags <script>...</script> in my javascript code

Comment: add your full code in jsfiddle and give the link i will check

Comment: choose `No wrap - in <head>` in left side drop down in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

The tes function is Ok..You just have a typo in here :

```
<button onclik="tes();">Load Data</button>
             ^
```